# tsconfig.json - Only build ts files from folder

Tags: typescript

I am currently trying to build my ts files into a single ts files. The issue I'm getting is that my code below isn't doing what I thought it would. I used sourceRoot to attempt to set the only place it could get the source from but that didn't work. I have also tried putting a . infront of the directory but it still pulls from everywhere :(

```js
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "ES5",
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "preserveConstEnums": true,
       "out": "www/js/app.js",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "sourceRoot": "www/app"
   }
}
```

all files including those not inside of www/app build :(

for now I've moved back to manually specifying the files:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "out": "www/js/app.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./www/app/app.ts",
        "./www/app/menu/menuController.ts",
        "./www/app/playlists/playlistsController.ts"
    ]
}
```

is it possible to restrict the source directories to be only www/app?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes,it is possible. Please use `rootDir` like `'rootDir': 'app'`, if `www` is your root dir of your application.

`rootDir` description from [typescript compiler options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> Specifies the root directory of input files.

Comment: I will try this when I get home. Thanks

Comment: Sure, @MichaelCrook. Just a note about `out` that this is option is deprecated. Now it is recommended to use `outFile`. Please see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options

Comment: Compiler options doc has been moved to: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 26):

This question is a bit older, I know. But some of the TypeScript compiler options mentioned here are not necessarily helpful to solve the question. For people searching `rootDir` or similar (like me), it may be helpful to clarify the mentioned and the solution-relevant options.

#### Emit all files into one single file

✅ Use `outFile`

❌ Don't use `out` (deprecated)

**Background:**

If you want to to build to a destination directory, choose `outDir`. See [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for further infos.

#### Only emit files from a certain directory

✅ Use `files`/`include`/`exclude` in tsconfig

❌ Don't use `rootDir`

**Explanation:**

The compiler finds all input files by

- looking at  `file`/`include`/`exclude` properties
- following `import` statements
- following  `///<reference .. />` (should not matter so much anymore)

If those options are not specified, all files in your TypeScript project root (given by tsconfig.json) will be included. The `import`ed modules are *automatically* included by the compiler, regardless of `file`/`include`/`exclude`  - have a look at their [FAQ](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#why-does-a-module-in-the-exclude-list-still-get-picked-up-by-the-compiler). All input files combined are the envelope of files it will build. How to configure `file`/`include`/`exclude`, see tsconfig.json [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details), consider also @TSV's answer.

#### rootDir

`rootDir` controls the *output* directory structure alongside with `outDir`,  it is *not* used to specify the compiler *input*. Its usage is ([quote](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25646#issuecomment-404900242)):

> For every input file (i.e. a .ts/.tsx file) it needs to generate an matching output (a .js/.jsx file). To figure out the file path of the generated output file it will chop off the "rootDir" from the input, then prepend the "outDir" to it.

Consequently `rootDir` needs a directory that includes all your input sources from above, otherwise you get

> error TS6059: File is not under 'rootDir' .. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

If `rootDir` is omitted, the compiler automatically calculates a suitable directory by considering all input files at hand. So it doesn't necessarily have to be set.

#### sourceRoot

This option is only relevant with sourcemaps/debugging and can be omitted for the scope of the question. It is used, when your sources files are at a different location at runtime than at design time. The compiler will adjust the paths to the sources in the sourcemap file to match the paths at runtime ([compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)).

Hope, that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: You can find more infos on `rootDir` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422458/error-ts6059-file-is-not-under-rootdir-rootdir-is-expected-to-contain-al/57429111#57429111).

Comment: very detailed answer, thanks

Answer (score 12):

According to the tsconfig [schema](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig):

> "If no 'files' property is present in a tsconfig.json, the compiler
>   defaults to including all files the containing directory and
>   subdirectories. When a 'files' property is specified, only those files
>   are included."
>
> "If no 'files' property is present in a tsconfig.json, but an
>   'exclude' property is present, the compiler will exclude the files and
>   folders specified in the 'exclude' property."

According to the [description](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json):

> The "files" property cannot be used in conjunction with the "exclude"
>   property. If both are specified then the "files" property takes
>   precedence.

The [issue 'support globs in tsconfig.json files property (or just file/directory exclusions)'](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927) reflects current situation.

Answer (score 5):

The `rootDir` is just used to control the output directory structure.

The output directory structure will be similar to your `rootDir`'s directory.
U can use the `glob-like file patterns` to restrict your source directories:

```
* matches zero or more characters (excluding directory separators)
? matches any one character (excluding directory separators)
**/ recursively matches any subdirectory
```