# How can I configure tsc to compile test specs from a specific folder?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm implementing e2e tests into an Angular project. It wasn't started with `@angular-cli`, so I'm configuring most of it manually.

What I'm trying to do now is to define a script in `package.json` to transpile only the specs in `tests/` folder to `tests/compiled`.

I tried to follow this question: [tsconfig.json - Only build ts files from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117191/tsconfig-json-only-build-ts-files-from-folder). It recommends to use `--rootDir` to define the folder.

But if I use this: `tsc --rootDir tests --outDir ./tests/compiled`, it compiles files from other folders anyways (like ./src). Also, it returns a lot of TS6059 errors, complaining that rootDir should contain all source files.

An example:
`error TS6059: File 'C:/Users/Betalabs/Documents/Projetos/Engine-Frontend/src/vendor.browser.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'tests'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

The file hierarchy is this. Please note that the test specs (`*.spec.ts`) I want to transpile are in the `tests/` folder.

```
(root)
-- src/
-- tests/
    -- compiled/
        -- (transpiled test files, ".js")
    -- helpers/
        -- (helper modules, ".ts")
    -- page-objects/
        -- (page objects, ".ts")
    -- forms.spec.ts
    -- filters.spec.ts
-- .gitignore
-- .tern-project
-- buildspec.yml
-- conf.js
-- package-lock.json
-- package.json
-- README.md
-- tsconfig.json
-- tsconfig.webpack.json
-- tslint.json
-- typedoc.json
-- webpack.config.js
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017.object"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "hammerjs",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

I'm "solving" this by compiling all files anyways and removing the unnecessary ones manually. In other words: a complete mess :P

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile those files, you can use

```
"include": ["tests"]
```

in your tsconfig

---

That being said, I think it'd be much more easier to convert the project to use ng cli :)
Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I'm on mobile but I'll try this solution as soon as possible.