# error TS6059: File is not under 'rootDir' .. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: typescript, tsc

I am getting this fairly non-sensical tsc transpilation error:

> error TS6059: File
>   '/Users/alex/codes/interos/teros-cli/src/logging.ts' is not under
>   'rootDir' '/Users/alex/codes/teros/notifier-server/src'. 'rootDir'
>   is expected to contain all source files.

my PWD is `/Users/alex/codes/teros/notifier-server` and the tsconfig.json file for `/Users/alex/codes/teros/notifier-server/tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "declaration": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

this seems like a bug..since teros-cli dir is outside the PWD, *and* is governed by a separate tsconfig.json file.

I even changed this field to:

```
  "include": [
    "/Users/alex/codes/teros/notifier-server/src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "/Users/alex/codes/teros/teros-cli"
  ]
```

still get the same error.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

#### What is `rootDir`?

[`rootDir`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) is set to a root folder, that contains *all* your source files. If not specified, TS will automatically choose a suitable parent folder of all inputs. `rootDir` also [determines the output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57434522/5669456).

#### What does the error mean?

My guess is you have an `import` statement for `logging.ts` somewhere in `notifier-server`:

```
import {logger} from "@teros-cli/logging" // or similar
```

Then `logging.ts` module will be [*automatically* included](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#why-does-a-module-in-the-exclude-list-still-get-picked-up-by-the-compiler) by the compiler, regardless of `include` and `exclude` options in `tsconfig.json`. One way to check all included files is `tsc --listFiles`.

A `tsconfig.json` file outside `notifier-server` doesn't help here. The compiler picks up exactly one config per `tsc` compilation and optionally pulls [inherited configs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends). If it cannot find one in `notifier-server` project root (where you started `tsc`), only then the compiler [searches upwards the parent directory chain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#using-tsconfigjson), until a config is found.

#### Possible solutions

One fix is to just remove `"rootDir": "src"` from compiler options, so it gets set automatically. Caution: `rootDir` will then consider both projects as inputs!

Alternative: You can add a separate `logging.ts` module contained in `notifier-server/src` project and drop the external `import`.

Hope, that helps!

Comment: Another option is to use Project References. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547) for dealing with `rootDir` issues and using Project Reference to manage interal dependencies. Things will start to make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error by duplicating `paths` in `tsconfig`s.
Removing the latter solved the issue:

```
// ./tsConfig.json
"paths": {
  "@myPackage": ["./myPackage/index.ts"],
},

// ./MY_OTHER_PACKAGE/tsConfig.json
"paths": {
 "@myPackage": ["../myPackage/index.ts"]
},
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is for angular libraries. For external libraries, I added the `paths` definition to the `tsconfig.lib.json` file.

<sub>tsconfig.lib.json</sub>

```js
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "../../../out-tsc/lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@tbtk/popover": ["dist/tbtk/popover"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible Problems

1- Circular dependencies

2- Package name should be the same as the defined path.

```
// libs/utils/package.json 
{
...
"name":"Should-Be-Same"
...
}



// tsconfig.json
{ 
...

"Should-Be-Same":["/libs/utils/lib/src/index.ts"]

...
}
```

3- Spelling error in the paths

Answer (score 0):

```
 -src
     index.ts
 -tsconfig.json
```

If in tsconfig.json its `"rootDir": "./src"` & `index.ts` is in root it doesn't work, make sure `index.ts` is inside `src`