# Nrwl build Library Error: File is not under rootDir

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

The error occurs when I use the library in another library.
Library import is working fine in the app but not working within libraries.
And not able to generate the build of a library.
All libraries are publishable.

Error:

[image: Error]

Nrwl.v13 Files Structure within lib folder:

[image: Nrwl.v13 Files Structure within lib folder]

Comment: ### I answered this question under this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422458/error-ts6059-file-is-not-under-rootdir-rootdir-is-expected-to-contain-al/77086501#77086501

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in one of our monorepo and it was caused by the fact that one of our library's name wasn't valid. We had something like @organisation/test-utils/e2e which we ended up renaming to @organisation/test-utils-e2e (take note of the / usage).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:

- After a while, I tried building the project again, `not under rootDir happened`, aghhh... !
- After spend hours of searching, I deleted `node_modules/.cache` folder and built successfully.

It seems in `nx 13`, even we specify `nx build --skip-nx-cache`, nx does not skip cache :|

**ORIGINAL**:

I had the same `not under rootDir` also.
The problem I had was a **Circular dependency**.

My project `lib-a` import `lib-b`, instead of using `paths` (which was: `@lib/lib-b`).
It was:

```
import { MyBClass } from '../lib-a/src/index.ts';
```

When I changed to:

```
import { MyBClass } from '@lib/lib-b';
```

It worked successfully.

What a headache :|

**HINT**:

- To prevent circular dependency, you can use `Ctrl + F` and find anything with `../<project-name>/src`.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to debug. It can be related to circular dependency issue. Are you sure you don't import code from library which import code from the same library ?
A import B
B import A

If this is the case, you should handle this by creating a C library which will be imported by A and B or find a solution for the A or B which will not depend on each other.

Code example will be helpful for help you.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10785#issuecomment-1158916416:

> There seems to have been an issue with a migration that was scheduled
> for a version but the migration itself was released in another
> version, so that might have caused the migration to not run in some
> scenarios. That migration should have added the following in `nx.json`
> for anyone having their `nx.json` extending from
> `nx/presets/core.json` or `nx/presets/npm.json`:
>
> ```
> {
>   ...
>   "pluginsConfig": {
>     "@nrwl/js": {
>       "analyzeSourceFiles": true
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Could you please add the above snippet to your `nx.json` and try again? If after applying the change it doesn't pick
> it up immediately, run `nx reset` and then try again.

This didn't work for me though, so I opened [nx issue #11583: library importing other library using wildcard path mapping fails with "is not under 'rootDir'"](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/11583)