# tsconfig paths care not working in component type files

Tags: angular, typescript, path, tsconfig

I got an angular project which I'm trying to migrate to the NX project. Everything worked fine until I added a new lib to the project by command:
`nx generate @nrwl/angular:library --name=shared --directory=libs`

And based on that commmand - the new path was added to the `tsconfig.base.json` and it looks like:

```
{
   "compileOnSave": false,
   "compilterOptions": {
       "baseUrl": ".",
       "downlevelIteration": true,
       "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "paths": {
           "@root/*": ["apps/application/src/app/*"],
           "shared": ["libs/shared/src/index.ts"]
       }
    }
}
```

And rigth now all modules frmo the `application` can see the `@root/` paths and `shared` but when it comes to the component type files (not all of them) like `feautre.component.ts` - the path is not visible but when it comes to `app.component.ts` - it works fine.

Any ideas on that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error TS6059: File is not under 'rootDir' .. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422458/error-ts6059-file-is-not-under-rootdir-rootdir-is-expected-to-contain-al)

Comment: Here is your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77086501/12603032